# Creating SQL DB from Parsing Url's

Tags: python, html, sql, database, parsing

i'm trying to get a SQL DataBase from a list of URL's that i want to parse. In thoses websites there's txt informations that i need and i want to put them into a DB to make some  filter research

my code is :

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f_out:
for i in range(100, 120):
data = 'www.website.com/{}\n'.format(i)
print(data)
f_out.write(data)
```

I guess the parsing would be something like that :

```
 wget -i files.txt
```

And the final result would be like :

```
MySQL or PostgreSQL of html files
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection():
 """ create a database connection to a database that resides
 in the memory """
try:
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
print(sqlite3.version)
except Error as e:
print(e)
finally:
conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
create_connection()
```

Anyone to help me make this work ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hello @MattM. I'm trying to parse some website and get a database in SQL from thoses adress

Comment: What have you tried? This question is really broad.

Comment: @MattM. Oh ok sorry. I tried  this just up